# Make the child element white when the parent item is hovered

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to do this without javascript and just using CSS?

I have a navigation. The text within the anchor elements are black. Upon hover of the line item the line item becomes orange. At that point I would like to alter the child anchor element text to be white.

What I have right now is an anchor tag rule to be white when hovered. Because the anchor is smaller than the line item it means that, hovering over the line item doesn't change the text to white straight away, only when the mouse hovers over the center, where the anchor tag is.

I could post html but I don't think its necessary. Is it? Hope I'm making sense and that my question is clear.

Put another way, I'd like to alter an element based upon the hover state of it's parent element.

Comment: Is `.parent:hover a {}` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to target the parent element using CSS selector. You can instead add a `:hover` rule to line item to change its background color. At the same time, add an additional rule that changes the color of the child link upon hover:

```
li:hover {
    background: orange;
}
li:hover a {
    color: white;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/L3ye8aeL/)

Comment: brilliant! Thanks a lot it's what I needed (though has opened up a separate unforeseen problem beyond the scope of my question). Thank you very much, accepting shortly. I did not know about using selectors post :hover

Comment: Note that in the demo I used padding on parent element. Actually you should set the links so that they are the same size as parent (move the padding to `a` and set `display: block`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Giving `a` tag `display:block;` will take the full width of your `li` element.

```
#menu li a:hover {
    background: #FC6;/*added*/
}
#menu a {
    color: #000;
    dispaly:block;/*added*/
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/L3ye8aeL/1/)**

Comment: Interesting I thought of trying to do that too depending on the response I got here. Thanks for taking the time to answer but I'm gonna go with @Salaman's answer with :hover a

Comment: Thats better choose according to your need and pleasure to help you.